# Wildfly Missing dependencies

Tags: java, jpa, wildfly

I am converting a glassfish application over to wildfly and I am having a problem with dependencies.

The error is:

```
{"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"Dashboard-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#dashboard\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.\"\\\"java:\".\"OracleDS\\\"\"]"]}
```

**Persistance.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="dashboard" transaction-type="JTA">
 <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>"java:/OracleDS"</jta-data-source>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output_mode" value="both"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**The standalone xml section that is invovled in the above error:**

```
 <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/OracleDS" pool-name="Oracle" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
```

**Module XML to do with the oracle:**

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.oracle">
   <resources>
    <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
   </resources>
 <dependencies>
   <module name="javax.api"/>
   <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
 </dependencies>
 </module>
```

There is obviously something incorrect with the the data source in the persistance.xml and the JNDI name in the standalone.xml but I am unable to get it to match.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there's a JDBC driver for your Oracle datasource.

Comment: I included the incorrect module xml file. I have now included the oracle module xml. I have used the admin console and connected to the oracle database successfully through the admin console.